# UnhandledPromiseRejectWarning

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs')
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:7545");


const contract_address = "0x7484d32e891817702c5d7c764dBF7e592000b415";


async function web3Contract() {
    const contract_abi = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Bottle.json', 'utf8')
    const Bottle = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(contract_abi).abi, contract_address);
    Bottle.methods.setName("Palm").send();
    Bottle.methods.getGreeting().call();
}

async function run() {
    try {
        await web3Contract();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Your error is this - ' + err);
    }    
}

run();
```

I'm getting a error "UnhandledPromiseRejectWarning". I been googling this for hours and can't seem to fix this. Please guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer 1: Don't evaluate `JSON.parse(contract_abi).abi` as a parameter. If you do there is no way checking what it is - and it is possibly causing the error. Better:

```
const contract_abi = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Bottle.json', 'utf8');
const abi = JSON.parse(contract_abi).abi;
console.log( abi); // do you get this far?
const Bottle = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);
```

Pointer 2: Don't log the string value of an error object when debugging - you will only get its `toString()` result which looks to be the same as logging `error.message`. Better:

```
 console.log('Your error is this - ', err);
```

Supplying `err` as a second argument causes `node` to log additional properties of the error object including [`error.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) which provides trace information.

Comment: Hey thank you for your time. I took your pointers and I log the abi and it works and I log the Bottle instance and it works. But when I get to ```Bottle.methods.setName("Palm").send();``` It throws these errors https://gyazo.com/fd69838fb9f1297e38d6ef6695856a50 & https://gyazo.com/8b3f1dea005687733dafc317e4191abd

Comment: @AngeloTree  Try taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve the question - additional information about how and when the error occurs should be edited into the question rather than comments.  Perhaps [web3.eth.Contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id14) is describing the `from` string `bottle.js` is looking for.